# Predicting out put of a Vgg16, confuse

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to understand what to we do with the result from a model.predict.

yhat = model.predict(image), what kind of return I am looking into, but it is an structure... but then I found this on the web which got me really confused...

Can someone help me understand model.predict([x])[0][0]

I am trying to get a value so I can see it is one thing or another. it is a two-class classification.

Thanks.

```
def get_predicition(image):
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    try: # If in case face is not detected at any frame
        face = face_detector(image, 1)[0]  # Face detection
        x, y, size = get_boundingbox(face=face, width=width, height=height) # Calling to get bound box around the face
    except IndexError:
        pass
    cropped_face = image[y:y+size, x:x+size] # cropping the face 
    output,label = evaluate(cropped_face) # Sending the cropped face to get classifier result 
    font_face = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX # font settings
    thickness = 2
    font_scale = 1
    if label=='Real':
        color = (0,255, 0)
    else:
        color = (0, 0, 255)
    x = face.left()    # Setting the bounding box on uncropped image
    y = face.top()
    w = face.right() - x
    h = face.bottom() - y
    cv2.putText(image, label+'_'+str('%.2f'%output)+'%', (x, y+h+30), 
            font_face, font_scale,
            color, thickness, 2) # Putting the label and confidence values

    return cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)# draw box over face

def evaluate(cropped_face):
    # Read the image and resize it
    img = cv2.resize(cropped_face, (224, 224))

    # Reshape
    x = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)
    x /= 255.

    result = model_Xc.predict([x])[0][0] # result = model_Xc.predict([x])[0][0]

    if result > 0.5:
        animal = "cat"
    else:
        animal = "dog"
        result = 1 - result

    return result, animal
```

Comment: What library is this?

Comment: I am using keras and vgg16 and vgg19

Comment: We’re going to need to see enough code that we can figure out exactly where that method comes from.

Comment: will this help you? but the question is what doe this do? predict([x])[0][0] ---- predict([x])[0]. thanks

Comment: I’m trying to figure out what it does, and in order to do that I need to know the type of `model_Xc`.

Comment: model_Xc = models.load_model('./models/VGG16_Adam011820.hdf5')

Comment: That doesn’t tell me the type either, though.

Comment: but what is that you need? I dont understand what do you need.

Comment: The type of `model_Xc`... The type will allow us to find the information we need on the `.predict()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = model_Xc.predict(img)[0][0]

res = 0.026140803
```

it gives you the minimun value from the result array

and

```
res = model_Xc.predict(img)[0][1]
```

it gives you the max value from the result array